# How to change Newsletter subscription message on order success page

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, order-email, cookie, magento2.4.1

When a new order is create and the customer has checked the Subscribe to Newsletter box, below is how the `checkout/onepage/success` page appears.

[image]

I will like to change the text `Thank you for your subscription.` to something different.

I have searched I located the text string here `magento/module-newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php`. I tested it by change the text on this method
`getSuccessMessage(int $status): Phrase{}` but it did not change on frontend.

When I look at the page source code I could see it is going from a cookie message below.

```
    <!-- ko if: cookieMessages && cookieMessages.length > 0 -->
    <div role="alert" data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }" class="message-success success message" data-ui-id="message-success">
            <div data-bind="html: $parent.prepareMessageForHtml(message.text)">Thank you for your subscription.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: messages().messages && messages().messages.length > 0 --><!-- /ko -->
```

I could not figure out how I can change it. I am still new to Magento 2. I will appreciate it if anyone can point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Newsletter Success Message comes from this file :

> Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction

If you open this file, there is function called `private function getSuccessMessage` which return this message.